# Как синхронизировать таблицы MySQL по крону?

Tags: shell, ssh, синхронизация, mysql

Подскажите решение, или может кто поделится скриптом, как можно синхронизировать таблицы на 2-х базах MySQL (одинаковых, просто на разных серверах). Подойдёт вариант переброса всей базы, главное, чтобы делалось автоматом по крону.

Дано - 1 база главная, с нее берем данные, есть доступ ssh, возможность размещать и запускать скрипты sh. но нет root-а, просто пользователь, у которого доступ к своим файлам и своим базам. 2 - база вспомогательная, которая должна получать данные с 1-й базы периодически, лучше отдельные таблицы, но можно и целиком базу. Есть доступ root, ssh, настроен удаленный доступ к базе на 2.

Как перелить с 1 на 2 таблицы? Желательно в сжатом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Ну самое простое.

По крону делаешь DUMP всей БД и сразу её DUMP.tar.gz. Скидываешь в нужную папку на этом же сервере.

С другого сервера подключаешься по ftp к папке в которой лежит DUMP.tar.gz копируешь его к себе, разархивируешь и дампишь в БД. вот и все.

Comment: это как раз самое простое. но ведь с 1-го сервера тоже все можно сделать? подключиться по ssh ко второму и выполнить все удаленно. С первого можно и по FTP прокачать на 2-й, так что файл окажется физически на 2-м. останется только все запустить с 1-го. Делать два крона и как-то их синхронизировать... По-моему может дать сбой.

Comment: Все может дать сбой!

Лучше все разбить на куски, чтобы было проще разбираться с ошибками.
Пусть геморойнее, но правильнее, отдать 1 серверу только создание дампа, а второй пусть забирает нужные ему файлы и у себя их там распаковывает и делает что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения такой задачи предназначен штатный [механизм репликации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html).